# Parse stream of data having JSON entries from log file using Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, generator

I have a requirement to parse stream of data which is almost in JSON format with some pretext in date format as shown below.

```
2020-09-28 15:52:13.633+0000 INFO |RestAPI.ServiceManager              | Request #399: {
                                                                         "context": {
                                                                             "httpContextKey": 18446744071313531680,
                                                                             "verbId": 2,
                                                                             "verb": "GET",
                                                                             "originalVerb": "GET",
                                                                             "uri": "/services/v2/installation/deployments",
                                                                             "protocol": "https",
                                                                             "headers": {
                                                                                 "X-OGG-Context": "services",
                                                                                 "X-OGG-Service": "ServiceManager",
                                                                                 "X-OGG-Version": "v2",
                                                                                 "X-OGG-Resource": "installation/deployments",
                                                                                 "Content-Length": "0",
                                                                                 "Accept": "application/json"
                                                                             },
                                                                             "host": "testing-db.com",
                                                                             "securityEnabled": true,
                                                                             "authorization": null,
                                                                             "requestId": 399,
                                                                             "uriTemplate": "/services/{version}/installation/deployments",
                                                                             "catalogUriTemplate": "/services/{version}/metadata-catalog/deployments"
                                                                         },
                                                                         "isScaRequest": true,
                                                                         "content": null,
                                                                         "parameters": {
                                                                             "uri": {
                                                                                 "version": "v2"
                                                                             }
                                                                         }
                                                                     }
                                                                     Response: {
                                                                         "context": {
                                                                             "httpContextKey": 18446744071313531680,
                                                                             "requestId": 399,
                                                                             "code": "200 OK",
                                                                             "headers": {
                                                                                 "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                                                                 "Expires": "0",
                                                                                 "Pragma": "no-cache",
                                                                                 "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains"
                                                                             },
                                                                             "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                                                             "contentType": "application/json"
                                                                         },
                                                                         "isScaResponse": true,
                                                                         "originScaRequest": {
                                                                             "context": {
                                                                                 "httpContextKey": 18446744071313531680,
                                                                                 "verbId": 2,
                                                                                 "verb": "GET",
                                                                                 "originalVerb": "GET",
                                                                                 "uri": "/services/v2/installation/deployments",
                                                                                 "protocol": "https",
                                                                                 "headers": {
                                                                                     "X-OGG-Context": "services",
                                                                                     "X-OGG-Service": "ServiceManager",
                                                                                     "X-OGG-Version": "v2",
                                                                                     "X-OGG-Resource": "installation/deployments",
                                                                                     "Content-Length": "0",
                                                                                     "Accept": "application/json"
                                                                                 },
                                                                                 "securityEnabled": true,
                                                                                 "authorization": null,
                                                                                 "requestId": 399
                                                                             },
                                                                             "isScaRequest": true
                                                                         },
                                                                         "content": {
                                                                             "$schema": "api:standardResponse",
                                                                             "links": [
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     "rel": "describedby",
                                                                                     "href": "https://testing-db.com/services/v2/metadata-catalog/deployments",
                                                                                     "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
                                                                                 }
                                                                             ],
                                                                             "messages": [],
                                                                             "response": {
                                                                                 "$schema": "ogg:installationDeployments",
                                                                                 "xagEnabled": false,
                                                                                 "deployments": [
                                                                                     {
                                                                                         "deploymentId": "39398e93-7e53-484c-9e90-3bf2f820ee73",
                                                                                         "deploymentName": "FOR-TMDB",
                                                                                         "enabled": true,
                                                                                         "status": "running"
                                                                                     },
                                                                                     {
                                                                                         "deploymentId": "30233230-94a6-4ae7-9b5e-db66105d9046",
                                                                                         "deploymentName": "ServiceManager",
                                                                                         "enabled": true,
                                                                                         "status": "running"
                                                                                     }
                                                                                 ]
                                                                             }
                                                                         }
                                                                     }
```

When `tail -0f apiserver.log | python parse` is run it should parse each JSON entry and fetch to display any entities like `DATE` and `Request` details. Note that log also has `Response` in JSON format which needs to be excluded.

I tried with below code leveraging generator, but issue is how to group multiple lines and then parse to fetch JSON entries ? As I need to exit for loop to get it but it will fail streaming.

```
import sys

def read_stdin():
    readline = sys.stdin.readline()
    while readline:
        yield readline
        readline = sys.stdin.readline()

for line in read_stdin():
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options (the second one is simpler and probably best):

1. You can use the `regex` package from the `PyPi` repository and try to recognize the Request `JSON` string as below:

```
import regex
import sys
import json


json_rex = regex.compile(r"""
(?<json> #capturing group json
 { #open {
 (?: #non-capturing group
    [^{}]++ #anything but {} without backtracking
  | #or
    (?&json) #recursive substitute of group expr
 )*
 } #close }
)
""", flags=regex.VERBOSE)

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if regex.search(r'Request #\d+: {', line):
        json_str = '{\n'
        while True:
            json_str += sys.stdin.readline()
            if json_rex.match(json_str):
                d = json.loads(json_str) # we have our dictionary
                print(d)
                break
```

2. Just try to parse accumulated lines as `JSON` until you get no error:

```
import re
import sys
import json


while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if re.search(r'Request #\d+: {', line):
        json_str = '{\n'
        while True:
            json_str += sys.stdin.readline()
            try:
                d = json.loads(json_str) # we have our dictionary, perhaps
            except Exception:
                pass
            else:
                print(d)
                break
```